# Передача данных из listview в другую активити

Tags: java, android

На первой активити есть listview, который заполняется через массив списков и выводиться в textview.
Как сделать, чтобы по клику определенного элемент listview, открывалась новая активити и туда передавались элементы из листвью

```
hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    hm.put(name, " Название");                 //Название
    hm.put(clas, " Класс");         //Описание
    hm.put(view, " Тип");
    hm.put(price, " 500  ");
    hm.put(img, R.drawable.kras40_main);

    flat.add(hm);
```

Надо чтобы эти переменные передались в textview в новой активити

Answer (score 1):

1. Необходимо реализовать `onItemClickListener`. В нем получать `id` элемента `listview`.
2. Стартовать активити через интент и передавать данные из `Map`.
3. Во второй активити принимать данные через интент, записывать в строки.
4. Значения строк передавать в нужный `view`.

Примерный код:
В первой активити:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)  {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Object obj = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    String value= obj.toString();
    Intent intent= new Intent(CurrrentClass.this,NextClass.class);
    intent.putExtra("value", value);                    
    startActivity(intent);    
}
```

Во второй активити:

```
Intent intent;
String value = intent.getExtra("value");
textview.setText(value);
```

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView, android.view.View, int, long)'

Cannot resolve method 'getListAdapter()' Ругается на 2 и 3 строчку

Comment: y ListView есть метод setOnItemClickListener( OnItemClickListener l ) используйте его, например так myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //обработка события здесь
            }
        };

Comment: Ну как реализовать метод нажатие и перехода на другую активити я понял как сделать, мне именно интересует как передать вместе с этим все данные в новую активити

Comment: @Keni, используя `intent.putExtra()`

Comment: Добился того, что все передается только в таком формате {name= Название, price= 500, clas= Класс, img= 2130837573}, можно как-то это разграничить?

Comment: @Keni, можно, получай позицию в `ListView` через `getItem(position)`, затем бери элемент `Map` с этой позицией и передавай в интент

Comment: а как взять элемент Map?

Comment: @Keni, нужно сделать итератор по `Map`, потому один элемент  - это пара, ключ - значение. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-to-efficiently-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-map